# Tight-binding: aren't the electronic bands just the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian?

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, orbitals, tight-binding

In the tight-binding model we choose a set of atomic orbitals $\{\phi_1(\textbf{r}), ..., \phi_N(\textbf{r})\}$ and estimate a *transfer matrix* and *hopping matrix*

$$
\begin{cases}
S_{ij}(\textbf{k}) = \langle \Phi_i(\textbf{k})\lvert\Phi_j(\textbf{k})\rangle\\
H_{ij}(\textbf{k}) = \langle \Phi_i(\textbf{k})\lvert \hat{H}\rvert\Phi_j(\textbf{k})\rangle
\end{cases}
$$
where
$$
\lvert \Phi_i(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle= \sum_{\textbf{R}}e^{i\textbf{k}\textbf{R}}\lvert\phi_i(\textbf{r}- \textbf{R})\rangle
$$

We ask for eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian
$$\hat{H}\lvert \Psi_j(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle = E_n(\textbf{k})\lvert \Psi_j(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle $$

were we express them as linear combinations

$$
\lvert \Psi_j(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle =  \sum_{j'}C_{jj'}\lvert \Phi_{j'}(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle
$$

This leads to the *secular system*

$$
det\big[H-E_n(\textbf{k})S\big] = 0
$$

and by solving it we find the electronic bands and eigenvectors.

Now I am very confused because the problem seemed to be solvable by simply representing the Hamiltonian in the basis of the $\lvert \Phi_i(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle$ vectors ($H_{ij}$) and diagonalising it.

**So my question is**: what's the point of doing the whole procedure (computing transfer and hopping matrix, solve secular system) if we can just calculate $H_{ij}$ and find its eigenvalues and eigenvectors? Aren't the electronic bands just the eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solid state physics $H_{ij}$ is most often initially unknown thing. The goal of tight-binding model is to actually construct this hamiltonian in reasonable fashion. So theorists do something like that:

1. Choose a set of basis functions (atomic orbitals in which electron wavefunctions are most expressed). For example, $p_z$ orbitals for carbon atoms in graphene and $d_{z^2}$, $d_{x^2-y^2}$, $d_{xz}$ orbitals for transition metal atoms in transition metal dichalcogenides.
2. Then they introduce energy parameters responsible for overlapping orbitals. For atoms from one sublattice there can be one such a parameter (it can be named as exchange integral or hopping parameter) and for atoms from different sublattices there can be another set of hopping parameters.

The logic of step 2 can differ. You can see in some papers that energy of overlapping orbitals is computed for example using Slater-Koster approximation. Also symmetries of the system can say something about this hopping as a function of wavevector $k$, so there are approaches where using defined symmetries the number of tight-binding parameters is reduced. Then these parameters are often fitted to ab initio calculations (often DFT).

So finally yes, if you know $H_{ij}$ you can compute dispersion just solving eigenvalues problem. But tight-binding model is not about just that, it is about the method using which you can build your matrix which you will diagonalize.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! To see if I got the point: if the only goal was to find eigenvectors and electronic bands it wouldn't be necessary to go through the whole procedure of finding $H_{ij}$ and $S_{ij}$ and then solving the secular system?

Comment: To find eigenvectors of a matrix you should firstly know what your matrix is. If you know $H_{ij}$ without tight-binging model assumptions (from my experience to be honest this is rarely a case) then yes, you can use it to calculate electronic structure.

Comment: But since we have to assume to know $H_{ij}$ and $S_{ij}$ in order to solve the secular system, what's the point of it? Or is this system involved in finding $H$ and $S$ somehow?

Comment: Yes, tight-binding model helps you to write down the hamiltonian (using some initial information about the nature of hoppings between neighbouring sites in material). And then you solve your hamiltonian - but that is not what called tight-binding model, you can do it in whatever way you like.

Comment: Sorry but I think I am still not getting it ^^' ... say I managed to write down $H$ and $S$ using tight-binding assumptions. Now I want to know the crystal Hamiltonian's eigenvalues (bands) and eigenfunctions. What I do is basically taking this equation $E_n(\textbf{k}) = \frac{\langle\Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\lvert\hat{H}\rvert\Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle}{\langle\Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\lvert\Psi_n(\textbf{r}, \textbf{k})\rangle}$ and manipulate untill I have the secular equation. What stops me from just taking $H$ and finding its eigenvectors instead?

Comment: If you have constructed your $H$ then you don't need actually to use your equation for $E_n(k)$. You of course can, and it will lead to the same result: this equation when $\psi_n$ are eigenvectors gives exactly your eigenvalues of a matrix. But if you don't know eigenvectors and don't want to calculate them then to calculate dispersion just find eigenvalues of your matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139114/discussion-between-andrea-and-goroshek).